# Migrating from SQL Server Express 2012 to MySQL no schemata listed

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am trying to migrate to MySQL from SQL Server Express 2012 but the migration wizard is unable to find the schemas from SQL Express even after connecting successfully to both databases.

[image: Database migration log]

[image: No schemata found]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the user permissions I was using to connect to the SQL server database. Using the `sa` account worked.